What agent to use with openSSH on windows in NodeJS
I am now making a connection with Linux servers, from Windows clients using a NodeJS cli, using this config:
    this.server.ftpConfig = {
      [...]
      agent: process.platform === 'win32' ? 'pageant' : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
      agentForward: process.platform !== 'win32',
    };

This works, even though I switched from Pageant to OpenSSH, because we use the WinSSH-Pageant bridge
As the readme says:

Proxy Pageant requests to the Windows OpenSSH agent (from Microsoft), enabling applications that only support Pageant to use openssh.

But I think I should be able to connect without using this bridge.
So far, I have found very little information on how to do this.
What kind of 'agent' should I use to connect using node-ssh package without anything Pageant?
And I guess the solution is the same for ssh2 package?

This seems to be the best solution, which will probably also work on MacOs and Linux, assuming environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set there:
  agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK ?? "\\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent",
  agentForward: true,

